# Postfix mail send issue?

Tags: linux

I am facing some issue in my postfix. I am not receiving any mail from postfix. The log file also doesn't show any error log. Log file is normal. On further analysis I found mail is going to incoming but not in active folder of postfix. Only one thing I found in maillog file:

**postfix/cleanup[30369]: warning: database /etc/postfix/virtual.db is older than source file /etc/postfix/virtual**

Rest of maillog file was normal.

I am able to find the issue. can any one help on this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Run:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
```

Then restart postfix.

The warning means that you have a text version and a hashmap version of the `virtual` file. The text version is the human readable one that you edit, then you build a hashmap of it using `postmap` and that's what postfix reads. It's just telling you that you may have made a change to the human readable one and forgot to create a new `.db` of it.

Comment: I had already faced this issue once . on restarting the postfix it got resolved but again this issue has occurred . Will this solve the problem forever.

Comment: @NiteshKumar it will solve it as long as nothing touches the `/etc/postfix/virtual` file. If that file gets touched or modified, and you **don't run postmap**, you'll see that error again.